# Reading a Turtle/N3 RDF File with Python

Tags: python, debugging, semantic-web, rdflib, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to encode some botanical data in [Turtle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_(syntax)) format, and read this data from Python using [RDFLib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). However, I'm having trouble, and I'm not sure if it's because my Turtle is malformed or I'm [misusing](http://code.google.com/p/rdflib/wiki/IntroParsing) RDFLib.

My test data is:

```
@PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@PREFIX p: <http://www.myplantdomain.com/plant/description> .
p:description a rdfs:Property .
p:name a rdfs:Property .
p:language a rdfs:Property .
p:value a rdfs:Property .
p:gender a rdfs:Property .
p:inforescence a rdfs:Property .
p:color a rdfs:Property .
p:sense a rdfs:Property .
p:type a rdfs:Property .
p:fruit a rdfs:Property .
p:flower a rdfs:Property .
p:dataSource a rdfs:Property .
p:degree a rdfs:Property .
p:date a rdfs:Property .
p:person a rdfs:Property .
p:c2a7b9a3-c54a-41f5-a3b2-155351b3590f
    p:description [
        p:name [
            p:kingdom "Plantae" ;
            p:division "Pinophyta" ;
            p:class "Pinopsida" ;
            p:order "Pinales" ;
            p:family "Pinaceae" ;
            p:genus "Abies" ;
            p:species "A. alba" ;
            p:language "latin" ;
            p:given_by [
                p:person p:source/Philip_Miller ;
                p:start_date "1923-1-2"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>
            ]
        ] ;
        p:name [
            p:language "english" ;
            p:value "silver fir"
        ] ;
        p:flower [
            p:gender "male"@en ;
            p:inflorescence "catkin"@en ;
            p:color "brown"@en ;
            p:color "yellow"@en ;
            p:sense "straight"@en
        ] ;
        p:flower [
            p:gender "female"@en ;
            p:inflorescence "catkin"@en ;
            p:color "pink"@en ;
            p:color "yellow"@en ;
            p:sense "straight"@en
        ] ;
        p:fruit [
            p:type "cone"@en ;
            p:color "brown"@en
        ]
    ] .
```

And my Python is:

```
import rdflib
g = rdflib.Graph()
#result = g.parse('trees.ttl') 
#result = g.parse('trees.ttl', format='ttl')
result = g.parse('trees.ttl', format='n3')
print len(g)
for stmt in g:
    print stmt
```

Which gives me the errors:

```
ValueError: Found @PREFIX when expecting a http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/grammar/n3#document . todoStack=[['http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/grammar/n3#document', []]]
```

I've tried varying the parse() parameters, but everything gives me an error. I've found little to no examples on how to parse Turtle. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the first problem is w/the *uppercase* `PREFIX`-- if you lowercase those it gets past that point.   Not sure if it's a bug in rdflib or in the Turtle `.ttl`, but the [Turtle Validator](http://www.rdfabout.com/demo/validator/) online demo seems to agree it's a problem with the `.ttl` (says `Validation failed: The @PREFIX directive is not supported, line 1 col 0.` but that problem goes away if you lowercase them).

Once you're past that hurdle, neither parser likes the part around `p:given_by [`: "Bad syntax (']' expected) at ^ in:"... per rdflib; Turtle Validator says

```
Validation failed: Expecting a period, semicolon, comma, close-bracket, or close-brace but found '/', line 31 col 33.
```

so it specifically dislikes the `p:source/Philip_Miller` part.

From these two issues (who knows if there are others...!) I think you can conclude that this N3 source (the `.ttl` file you post) is broken, and turn your attention to whatever system **made** this file in the first place, and why it's making it in such a multiply broken way.

Comment: Thanks. Changing that line to <source/Philip_Miller> seems to fix the problem.